# Uncaught Type error: undefined is not a function while creating an object

Tags: javascript

**Base64.js**

```js
var Base64 = {
  _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
  encode: function(e) {
    var t = "";
    var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
    var f = 0;
    e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
    while (f < e.length) {
      n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
      r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
      i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
      s = n >> 2;
      o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
      u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
      a = i & 63;
      if (isNaN(r)) {
        u = a = 64
      } else if (isNaN(i)) {
        a = 64
      }
      t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
    }
    return t
  }
}
```

I am calling encode method from another file like below
 had imported `base64.js` file and created object

```
Var base64=new Base64.encode(input);
```

Error:

> Uncaught Type error: undefined is not a function

Can any one help?

Comment: it should be `var` and not `Var`

Comment: Just a random guess, but how about `var base64 = new Base64().encode(input)`....?

Comment: Another `Base64._utf8_encode(e);` but `_utf_encode` is not defined

Comment: My intention here is wanted to call encode method from another Js file.

Answer (score 1):

#### Errors in your code:

1. `Var` should be `var`
2. `_utf8_encode`  is not defined.
3. You are returning encoded string. You do not need to create object. Just do `var encodedStr = Base64.encode(input)`
4. In this line

   ```
   t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
   ```

   in your original code, `this` refers to the object created by `new`, not `Base64`, so `this._keyStr` is `undefined`. But if you directly call `Base64.encode()` (#3 above), it will refer to `Base64` and you will get proper values.

```js
var Base64 = {
  _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
  encode: function(e) {
    var t = "";
    var n, r, i, s, o, u, a;
    var f = 0;
    e = Base64._utf8_encode(e);
    while (f < e.length) {
      n = e.charCodeAt(f++);
      r = e.charCodeAt(f++);
      i = e.charCodeAt(f++);
      s = n >> 2;
      o = (n & 3) << 4 | r >> 4;
      u = (r & 15) << 2 | i >> 6;
      a = i & 63;
      if (isNaN(r)) {
        u = a = 64
      } else if (isNaN(i)) {
        a = 64
      }
      t = t + this._keyStr.charAt(s) + this._keyStr.charAt(o) + this._keyStr.charAt(u) + this._keyStr.charAt(a)
    }
    return t
  },
  _utf8_encode: function(e) {
    // do your processing
    return e
  }
}

var input = "Hello World";
var base64 = Base64.encode(input);
console.log(base64)
```

[Rectified JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/63y3t31L/2/)

**Note:** I have defined `_utf8_encode`, but it returns same text. Please add necessary code.

Comment: Got me again (on `this`). :-) My eyes are unhappy today. I was able to sneak in a ninja above, though. ;-)

Comment: Even I updated similar, but your version is better. Thanks :-)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't get the "conflicting edit" notification. We were **one second** apart! :-)

Comment: Please let me know how I can call encode method from another Js file.....I have added all necessary imports like <script src="/base64.js> tag but when I am trying to call encode method getting error

Comment: @MadhuNali try logging `Base64` in console. You will get entire thing. Then just do `var output = Base64.encode(input)`